# How to test a Vue component that has a child component with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, jestjs, components

I'm new to frontend testing and I've now spent more than two day trying to test a component without making any progress.

My component **CreateStoryForm** looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>Title</v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-form>
        <base-btn-text
          @click="cancel()"
          class=cancel
        >
          Cancel
        </base-btn-text>
      </v-form>
    </v-card-text
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
  ...
  methods: {
    cancel() {
        this.$emit('cancel');
    },
  }
</script>
```

**base-btn-text** is a simple a custom component that is registered globally in **main.js**.

```
Vue.component('base-btn-text, BaseButtonText);
```

I now want to test the Form component with Jest and see if the event 'cancel' is emitted when pressing the button. However I can only make it work when I use a default button tag instead of my custom BaseButtonText-component.

What I tried:

1. Using a stub:

   ```
    wrapper = shallowMount(CreateStoryForm, {
      ...
      stubs: {
        'base-btn-text': true
     }
   ```

-> `wrapper.find('base-btn-text-stub').trigger('click');` does not emit an event

2. Using a stub with implementation:

   ```
    const CancelButton = "<button @click='cancel()'>Cancel</button>"
    ...
    wrapper = shallowMount(CreateStoryForm, {
      ...
      stubs: {
        'base-btn-text': CancelButton
     }
   ```

-> `wrapper.find('base-btn-text-stub');` or `wrapper.find('base-btn-text');` does not return anything

3. Importing and registering the child component in the test itself:

   ```
    import BaseButtonText ...
    Vue.component('base-btn-text, BaseButtonText);
   ```

-> `wrapper.find(BaseButtonText).trigger('click');` does not emit an event

And now I'm completely lost.